# Remove last node of linked list by passing it in to a void?

Tags: c, nodes

This code removes the head of the linked list when the list is used as a parameter in a void.

```
void removeNode(node** head) {
    (*head) = NULL;
}
```

How should I change this code to set the last item of the list that is used as an argument to NULL?

Note: I call this method from a main void and I want the list that is used as the 'head' parameter to have NULL as its last node.

Comment: What do you mean by removing ? Deleting ?. The allocated memory needs to be freed by using free(ptr).

Comment: "Passing it in to a void"?

Comment: "This code removes the head of the linked list" Why would you want to do this? Are you trying to implement some kind of FIFO? "the list is used as a parameter in a void" In a what? "How should I change this code to set the last item of the list that is used as an argument to NULL?" If this is what you want to do, then why pass head as a pointer-to-pointer? "main void" What is a main void?

Answer (score 1):

```
void removeLastNode(node ** head)
{
    if(!head || !(*head) || !(*head->next))
        return;
    node * tmp = *head;
    node * new_last;
    // Reach the last node
    for(;tmp->next;)
    {
        new_last = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    freeNode(tmp);
    tmp = NULL;
    new_last->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: @Coconop do you mean setting the value to NULL is deleting? The allocated memory is not freed still

Comment: @Coconop this doesn't actually set the node to NULL though.. Don't I need to also set the previous node to NULL?

Comment: @Coconop: Where is `tmp` initialized? You missed the case, in which `head` is `NULL`/list is `EMPTY`, here `tmp->next` will give error